# c++ wrapping to c# by passing handle decelrator

Tags: c#, c++, clr

I have a function in c++ like this which has another function inside it like this:

```
Doom(int n, const array<double> ^x, int incx, int k, double r){
     pin_ptr<double> xptr = &(x[0]);
     fdoom(n, xptr, incx, &k, &r, &fail);
}
```

now when I call this function from c#:

```
int k = 0;
double r = 0.0;
CPPCode.Doom(n, x, incx,  k, r);
```

here my values k and r should change to 1 and -2 but this doesn't happen. So I have to use refrence for this to happenbut I am totally confused about how to use CLR reference for a single value.

note that the function fdoom is defined like this in it's class:

```
void    fdoom (Integer n, const double x[], Integer incx,
        Integer *k, double *r, NagError *fail)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In managed C++ you should use `%` if you want to call it by reference from C#. 
That is your function look likes this:

```
Doom(int n, const array<double> ^x, int incx, int %k, double r){
     pin_ptr<double> xptr = &(x[0]);
     pin_ptr<int> kptr = &k;
     fdoom(n, xptr, incx, kptr, &r, &fail);
}
```

and in your C# function you should use `ref` keyword to call it by reference. That is:

```
CPPCode.Doom(n, x, incx, ref k, r);
```